# Compiling from within any file in a project in WinEdt

Tags: winedt

I have a `*.tex` file open in `WinEdt` which `input`s a few other `.tex` files.

Previously, I was able to compile my files by hitting <kbd>F9</kbd> from within any of the files in the Tree panel. But now after any change, I have to go to the main file (at the top of the Tree) and compile from there, which is a bit cumbersome. Any ideas how I can get WinEdt (version 8.0) to compile from anywhere by hitting <kbd>F9</kbd>?

Comment: Set the main file (menu project or with strg+F5)

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the main file by going to  `Project` → `Set Main File` with `main.tex` file open in the current tab. Alternatively you can use the short cut  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>F5</kbd> as commented by Ulrike Fischer. The third option is to use the tool bar button:

[image]

If I press the button shown by arrow, the file `doii.tex` becomes the main file (for example). The second button will do the reverse i.e., it will remove the main file status.

Note that by declaring main file, you are using a project and if you don't create a new project (under Project menu), the default project file `Winedt.prj` will be used.